# Бан страницы сайта в файле hosts

Tags: windows, hosts

Как в файле hosts забанить не весть сайт, а только определенную страницу? К примеру https://www.google.de/this_page_i_want_ban/

Comment: Никак, потому что hosts служит для сопоставления доменного имени IP-адресам.

Answer (score 4):

короткий ответ: никак.

---

более длинный ответ:

этот файл предназначен для сопоставления ip-адреса и доменного имени.

хранящаяся в нём информация не имеет никакого отношения к протоколу http, в рамках которого происходит передача информации о [url](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL), которую вы и хотите «банить».

когда [dns](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS) ещё не существовало, он был весьма актуален. нынче же практически используется лишь для сопоставления локальных адресов и имён, и для временной (а иногда и постоянной) подмены dns-ответов.